# "Cannot instantiate metavariable P of type ..." when destructing in Coq proof mode

Tags: coq

I have a problem in proving trivial proposition.

First, We define a composition of function with general domain and codomain:

```
Definition fun_comp {X Y Z W}
  (f : X -> Y) (g : Z -> W) (H : Y = Z) : X -> W.
destruct H. refine (fun x => g (f x)). Defined.
```

We will now try to prove a trivial lemma:

```
Lemma compose_trivial {X Y Z} (f : X -> Y) (g : Y -> Z) (H : Y = Y)
  : forall x, fun_comp f g H x = g (f x).
Proof.
  intros x. revert f g. destruct H.
```

But `destruct H.` fails with an error message:

```
Cannot instantiate metavariable P of type
"forall a : Type, Y = a -> Prop" with abstraction
"fun (Y : Type) (H : Y = Y) =>
forall (f : X -> Y) (g : Y -> Z), fun_comp f g H x = g (f x)"
of incompatible type
"forall Y : Type, Y = Y -> Prop".
```

If it is able to generalize `Y` in the right hand side of `H` independently, the `destruct` tactic would work, but it would contradict to the right hand side of the goal `g (f x)`.

Is it possible to prove `trivial_compose`? If possible, how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not trivial at all. This has to do with uniqueness of identity proof that is not provable in Coq. You need an extra axiom.
For example,

```
Require Import ProofIrrelevance.

Lemma compose_trivial {X Y Z} (f : X -> Y) (g : Y -> Z) (H : Y = Y)
  : forall x, fun_comp f g H x = g (f x).
Proof.
  intros x.
  now rewrite <- (proof_irrelevance _ (eq_refl Y) H).
Qed.
```